# Neural Network Python Gradient Descent

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, gradient-descent

I am new to machine learning and trying to understand it (self-learning). So I grabbed a book (this one if interested: [https://www.amazon.com/Neural-Networks-Unity-Programming-Windows/dp/1484236726](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484236726)) and started to read the first chapter. While reading, there are a few things I did not understand so I went to research online.
However, I still have trouble with a few points that I cannot understand even after so much reading and research:

1. How are we calculating l2_delta and l1_delta? (marked with #what is this part doing? in code below)
2. How does gradient descent relate? (I looked up the formula and tried to read a bit about it but I could not relate the one line code to the code I have down there)
3. Is that a network with 3 layers (layer 1: 3 input nodes, layer 2: not sure ,layer 3: 1 output node )

Neural Network Full Code:

## trying to write my first neural network!

```
import numpy as np

#activation function (sigmoid , maps value between 0 and 1)
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
def derivative(x):
    return x*(1-x)


#initialize input (4 training data (row), 3 features (col))
X = np.array([[0,0,1],[0,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]])

#initialize output for training data (4 training data (rows), 1 output for each (col))
Y = np.array([[0],[1],[1],[0]])


np.random.seed(1)


#synapses
syn0 = 2* np.random.random((3,4)) - 1
syn1 = 2* np.random.random((4,1)) - 1




for iter in range(60000):
    #layers
    l0 = X
    l1 = sigmoid(np.dot(l0,syn0))
    l2 = sigmoid(np.dot(l1,syn1))
    #error
    l2_error = Y - l2
    if(iter % 10000 == 0): #only print error every 10000 steps to save time and limit the amount of output
        print("Error L2: " + str (np.mean(np.abs(l2_error))))
    
    #what is this part doing?
    l2_delta = l2_error * derivative(l2)
    l1_error = l2_delta.dot(syn1.T)
    
    l1_delta = l1_error * derivative(l1)
    if(iter % 10000 == 0): #only print error every 10000 steps to save time and limit the amount of output
        print("Error L1: " + str (np.mean(np.abs(l1_error))))
    
    #update weights 
    syn1 = syn1 + l1.T.dot(l2_delta) // derative with respect to cost function
    syn0 = syn2 + l0.T.dot(l1_delta)
    
    
print(l2)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In general, layerwise computations (Hence the notation l1 and l2 above) is simply getting the dot product of a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and a vector of weights in the same dimension, then applying the sigmoid function on each component .

Gradient Descent. - - - Imagine, in two dimensions say the graph of $f(x) = x^2$ Suppose, we don't know how to get it's minimum. Gradient descent will basically evaluate $f'(x)$ at various points, and check whether $f'(x)$ is  close to zero